# Cannot export 'Buffer'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module

Tags: angular, typescript, buffer

i want to change the styling of an opensource app developed with angular and when i tried to build it with `ng build --watch` i get the following error :
 `Error: node_modules/@types/node/buffer.d.ts:90:14 - error TS2661: Cannot export 'Buffer'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.`
What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Something with ngModules export, I guess. Please share code of app.module or corresponding module of the component.

Comment: I have attached the code for the file app.module.ts here : https://codepen.io/Anis-k/pen/XWRLaEX

Comment: and here's the file where the error occurs : https://codepen.io/Anis-k/pen/GRmbMje

Comment: Had this same thing on an Angular project, the issue turned out to be jdenticon: https://github.com/dmester/jdenticon/releases/tag/3.1.1

Answer (score 3):

I know that it is not the best solution to the problem, but at least it allows us to continue while the github community manages to give some resolution to the bug

In the `tsconfig.json` add or change `"skipLibCheck": false`

Bibliography:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26086
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/62134
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck

Comment: Thanks so much.  I needed this because of https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/8544